# magento2 custom categories not displaying after overdiding

Tags: magento2

Why my custom module is not loading the categories.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Category\View" />
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Result" />
<preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Navigation" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
<!-- <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" /> -->
```

I **get :**   Where is the problem in overriding.

[image]

Comment: Have you end config node </config>

Comment: Yes it's ended.. Or else I wud ve got error in setup upgrade

Comment: Is it template issue or issue of override  block or